# Can keypad common be connected to microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, switches, keyboard

I want to use a keypad with a microcontroller. An example schematic is shown below. The pins 1, 2 and 3 are inputs with internal pull up resistors enabled and the pin 4 is output set to LOW. The real application will have much more switches.

My question is about the pin 4. Can I ground the keypad through the microcontroller? Or is it somehow stupid? Id like to do so because it would give me flexibility to set the grounding pin in software and the circuit could be more easily changed later. The switches and the MCU are on different circuit boards connected with a cable. That way the switch board could be changed without much attention to pinout.

One potential problem i've thought is what will happen if someone depresses all the buttons at once. Then all the current from the pull up resistors would go to the pin 4. I calculated how much it would be but it turned out not to be a problem.

Is there something else to consider?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEvJ1s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: have you done any research about connecting a keypad to a microcontroller?

Comment: I'm not sure what this buys you? What changes would you make later that wouldn't require a new board anyway?

Comment: For three buttons, it makes no difference. But you said you will add buttons, so it might make sense to make it a matrix. What you now have is a start of matrix that can be scanned with software. Only one more pin and you have 6 buttons for example. But if the wire is long and there is a possibility for electromagnetic interference or ESD that can destroy stuff, I'd consider anyway connecting a ground wire or several between PCBs.

Comment: I have already prototyped the system so that each switch has its own pin on the microcontroller. The firmware is also almost ready. The prototype has switch ground hard wired.

Comment: I'm confused. Why not connect the three switches directly to the circuit's ground node?  Why connect the switches to pin 4 on the microcontroller, which presumably is a general-purpose digital I/O pin that the software (a) configures as an output pin and (b) clears to create a logic LOW output signal that acts as a pseudo-ground signal. Is there a particular reason for doing this?